# PHP undefined variable in construct

Tags: php, undefined

Here is my code:

```
<?php
require dirname(__DIR__).'/config/Redirect.php';

class Parsing {

    private $controller = null;
    private $model = null;
    private $parameters = array();

    private $redirect;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->redirect = new Redirect($controller, $model, $parameters); //error is on this line
    }

}
?>
```

The error I am getting is this (i removed the line number but I commented where the error is in the above code):

```
Notice: Undefined variable: controller in /var/www/html/application/config/Parsing.php on line #

Notice: Undefined variable: model in /var/www/html/application/config/Parsing.php on line #

Notice: Undefined variable: params in /var/www/html/application/config/Parsing.php on line #
```

it seems like controller is already defined right above it such as `private $controller = null;` and all the other ones. what could be the problem?

Comment: like how you call the redirect, call those private variables as $this->

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the line to:

```
$this->redirect = new Redirect($this->controller, $this->model, $this->parameters);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `$this` keyword to call Class level variable

```
public function __construct() {
        $this->redirect = new Redirect($this->controller, $this->model, $this->parameters); 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your need `$this` keyword like `$this->controller`, `$this->model`, `$this->parameters`

```
public function __construct() {
        $this->redirect = new Redirect($this->controller, $this->model, $this->parameter); //error is on this line
}
```